# Effects on max_load_factor and bucket count when clearing an unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

If I do `unordered_map.clear()` will this change the `max_load_factor` or the `max_bucket_count` ?

Answer (score 1):

No - table 103 in the C++11 Standard says `clear` just erases the elements, leaving `empty()` true.  You can safely assume that it doesn't make other unrelated, undocumented changes.  Even if you've changed `max_load_factor` from the default of 1.0, it won't be modified again by `clear()`.

`max_bucket_count` is very likely hard-coded to `size_t(-1)` on most systems - variable system memory, swap/virtual memory etc., other processes competing for it, dynamic OS buffers/memory usage etc. make it impractical to return a meaningful value, so most programs shouldn't bother with it.  (It might - now or in some utopian future - have some vaguely meaningful value on a gew embedded systems or toy C++-like systems with fixed process memory, or "micro" spatial optimisations like use of a smaller (e.g. 16-bit) type for indexing buckets.)  Regardless, there's no logical reason to think that clearing a container would influence the `max_bucket_count` to be different from the pre-`clear` value.

Comment: and what about the bucket count (I assume this is what the asked intended)? if I set a size using reserve() then call clear() will the reserved size stay? I guess that the answer is positive just want to make sure

Comment: @user2717954: same observations re table 103 *suggests* the bucket count wouldn't change (FWIW, that'd be in keeping with `std::vector()` which won't shrink its memory usage after `clear`).